# Div Not Floating When Text Wraps to Second Line?

Tags: html, css

I ran into a floating/alignment issue and can't seem to figure it out. When I float some DIVs next to each other they all line up like they should... until the text from one of the DIVs falls to a second line.

If you look below you can see how Line 1 shows up. As you can see, ABCD sits next to the other DIVs on the same line.

On Line 2 you can see how EFGH falls to another line, even though there's plenty of space for it on the previous line.

How can I make it so the DIVs always sit next to each other regardless of how many lines of text there are?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

```css
#sample-list {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  background: orange;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.sample-overview {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-family: "open sans", "arial";
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.sample-name-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;
}

.sample-name {
  float: left;
}

.sample-dash {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.sample-div {
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="sample-list">

  <div class="sample-line">
    <div class="sample-overview">
      <div class="sample-name-wrap">
        <div class="sample-name">
          <a href="">Line 1: ostrum exercitationem ullam corporis</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-dash">–</div>
        <div class="sample-div">ABCD</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sample-line">
    <div class="sample-overview">
      <div class="sample-name-wrap">
        <div class="sample-name">
          <a href="">Line 2: atis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab sdaf sfffdaf ntoowerf jdj</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-dash">–</div>
        <div class="sample-div">EFGH</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sample-line">
    <div class="sample-overview">
      <div class="sample-name-wrap">
        <div class="sample-name">
          <a href="">Line 3: vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim</a>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-dash">–</div>
        <div class="sample-div">IJKL</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CODEPEN**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEqjRo

Comment: Just a comment that hopefully helps in terms of understanding _why_ - the div content sits in a box that is as wide as its content. Thus although the last line in div2 doesn't take up the whole width, the box that contains it certainly takes up the whole width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inline elements instead of floated divs fixes the issue. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VyQGWM?editors=1100.

```
<div id="sample-list">

    <div class="sample-line">
        <div class="sample-overview">
            <div class="sample-name-wrap">
                <a href="">Line 1: ostrum exercitationem ullam corporis</a>
                <span class="sample-dash">
                    –
                </span>
                <span class="sample-span">
                    ABCD
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sample-line">
        <div class="sample-overview">
            <div class="sample-name-wrap">
                <a href="">Line 2: atis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab sdaf sfffdaf ntoowerf jdj</a>
                <span class="sample-dash">
                    –
                </span>
                <span class="sample-span">
                    EFGH
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sample-line">
        <div class="sample-overview">
            <div class="sample-name-wrap">
                <a href="">Line 3: vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim</a>
                <span class="sample-dash">
                    –
                </span>
                <span class="sample-span">
                    IJKL
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
#sample-list {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    background: orange;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.sample-overview {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-family: "open sans", "arial";
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.sample-name-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: normal;
}
.sample-dash {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.sample-span {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

If you'd like to see why this is happening visit https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaQVqP. The only change is a CSS border which illustrates why your floated div is wrapping to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below. I think you dont need to use floats at all. Use spans instead. They have inline display property.

```css
.container {
max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla
  <span> - </span>
  <span> ABCD </span>
  </div>

  <div>
  Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla
  <span> - </span>
  <span> EFG </span>
  </div>

  <div>
  Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla
  <span> - </span>
  <span> HIJ </span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try With css Display property.
set `Display: inline;` to container so that DIVs inside container div sit next to each other. 
Hope this helps!